# Android radio button style definition

Tags: android, radio-button, themes, appearance

How can I make sure that the radio button appearance for 2 different projects is the same?

I copied what I thought were all of the relevant files and code from one project to another, but the radio buttons (and some other features, like the title bar) appear different.  It's like the activity_main.xml file is being interpreted differently, or there's a different set of defaults.  They have the same target & min sdk, and they reference the same base theme, and have the same activity_main.xml file.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the original code, that has the look I want, was written on the Android IDE that was available about a year ago.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track. My first guess would have been the theme and style used. I do not believe the version of the Android IDE will have anything to do with this. I would look a little bit more closely at the themes. See if you have multiple styles defined based on OS versions and make sure you copy all of them. My only other guess is that the theme or style is being updated in the code in one of the projects.

Comment: Yes, I just discovered that I have multiple "values" resources in my original project (for different APIs, apparently), and I had copied the wrong one.  I needed what was in "values-v11" (Theme.Holo.Light) and I had used what was in just plain "values" (Theme.Light).  Looks like I need to do some more research on themes!